# Multi-nested Json import to google sheets, No logical sorting and gives range error

Tags: json, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script

I'm trying to import a multi-nested Json into google sheets pulled from an API. I have a working macro but now the API is being updated to v2 and the new Json is nested completely different and with deeper nesting-levels.

I have tried tweaking the code I have but I can for my life not understand how to access the data from the returned array.

The old code I have that works for v1 of the API looks like this:

```
function getDailyCMCRates() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("cmcDailyRates");

 //ss.setSpreadsheetLocale('en-SE');

var url="https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=0"; 
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); // get feed
var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); //
var dataSet = dataAll;
var rows = [],dataAll;
for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
data = dataSet[i];
var d=new Date(data.last_updated*1000)// convert to date
var cmcLink = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/" + (data.id) 
//Create link 

rows.push([data.id,data.name,data.symbol,data.rank,data.market_cap_usd,data.price_usd,data.price_btc,data.percent_change_1h*0.01,data.percent_change_24h*0.01,data.percent_change_7d*0.01,d,cmcLink]);
}
dataRange = sheet.getRange(10, 1, rows.length, 12); //Last digit denotes 
columns
dataRange.setValues(rows);

}
```

The v1 API is available at https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=0

Version 1 of the Api is going offline shortly so for future reference here is a snippet of the returned Json:

```
[
{
"id": "bitcoin", 
"name": "Bitcoin", 
"symbol": "BTC", 
"rank": "1", 
"price_usd": "7683.43", 
"price_btc": "1.0", 
"24h_volume_usd": "4643650000.0", 
"market_cap_usd": "131891162381", 
"available_supply": "17165662.0", 
"total_supply": "17165662.0", 
"max_supply": "21000000.0", 
"percent_change_1h": "-0.12", 
"percent_change_24h": "3.17", 
"percent_change_7d": "18.05", 
"last_updated": "1532342660"
}, 
{
"id": "ethereum", 
"name": "Ethereum", 
"symbol": "ETH", 
"rank": "2", 
"price_usd": "464.953", 
"price_btc": "0.0605005", 
"24h_volume_usd": "1519310000.0", 
"market_cap_usd": "46898395231.0", 
"available_supply": "100866959.0", 
"total_supply": "100866959.0", 
"max_supply": null, 
"percent_change_1h": "0.25", 
"percent_change_24h": "0.05", 
"percent_change_7d": "0.21", 
"last_updated": "1532342670"
}
]
```

The new v2 API is available at https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/
There are no errors in the Json.

The code I started updating for the v2 API looks like this:

```
function getDailyCMCRates() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("getAPI");

var url="https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/"; 
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); // get feed
var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); //
var dataSet = dataAll;
var rows = [],dataAll;
for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {

data = dataSet[i];
rows.push([data.rank, data.name, data.website_slug, data.symbol,  data.id, data.circulating_supply, data.total_supply, data.max_supply, data.quotes.USD.price, data.quotes.USD.market_cap, data.quotes.USD.percent_change_1h, data.quotes.USD.percent_change_24h, 
data.quotes.USD.percent_change_7d, data.last_updated]);
}

}
dataRange = sheet.getRange(10, 15, rows.length, 14); //Last digit 
denotes columns
dataRange.setValues(rows);

var values=[[ dataAll.metadata.timestamp]]
sheet.getRange("B3").setValues(values)

var values=[[ dataAll.metadata.num_cryptocurrencies]]
sheet.getRange("B4").setValues(values)

var values=[[ dataAll.metadata.error]]
sheet.getRange("B5").setValues(values)
}
```

When I run this code I get an error saying "The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid." referring to the line

```
dataRange = sheet.getRange(10, 15, rows.length, 14);
```

The new Json looks like this:

```
{
 "data": {
    "1": {
        "id": 1, 
        "name": "Bitcoin", 
        "symbol": "BTC", 
        "website_slug": "bitcoin", 
        "rank": 1, 
        "circulating_supply": 17008162.0, 
        "total_supply": 17008162.0, 
        "max_supply": 21000000.0, 
        "quotes": {
            "USD": {
                "price": 9024.09, 
                "volume_24h": 8765400000.0, 
                "market_cap": 153483184623.0, 
                "percent_change_1h": -2.31, 
                "percent_change_24h": -4.18, 
                "percent_change_7d": -0.47
            }
        }, 
        "last_updated": 1525137271
    }, 
    "1027": {
        "id": 1027, 
        "name": "Ethereum", 
        "symbol": "ETH", 
        "website_slug": "ethereum", 
        "rank": 2, 
        "circulating_supply": 99151888.0, 
        "total_supply": 99151888.0, 
        "max_supply": null, 
        "quotes": {
            "USD": {
                "price": 642.399, 
                "volume_24h": 2871290000.0, 
                "market_cap": 63695073558.0, 
                "percent_change_1h": -3.75, 
                "percent_change_24h": -7.01, 
                "percent_change_7d": -2.32
            }
        }, 
        "last_updated": 1525137260
    } 
    ...
},
"metadata": {
    "timestamp": 1525137187, 
    "num_cryptocurrencies": 1602, 
    "error": null
}
}
```

This is how I would like the data to be arranged in google sheets: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vR6RoztbXk9q7gfPoYQUE-vwgQZkmS9Gy_cHKMuvCnoqOpeeDS1JWsEfVI2nXb2M1_7TmDT5XWGMkPN/pubhtml

I do understand that my code isn't addressing the keys in the parsed Json correctly, but with the Json being categorized differently for every subset I am completely lost on how to access it. Each subset of data I want to extract is nested "data">"1" for the first, "data">"2" for the second and so on. On top of that there is a subset within the subset. To many dimension LOL.

I've searched and googled but I only really find explanations of how multi-dimensional arrays work, not how to address and work with such an array in google script. And the little I do find is not relevant to finding a solution, not to my understanding at least.

I've experimented with changing how I address the keys in the array in every way I can imagine but to no avail. 
Also I tried to pull the dataset one by one, but with thousands of datasets that is feasibly impossible.

I have very limited java knowledge so sorry if this question comes by as a bit stupid! I do code a bit of VBA so I'm not completely unaccustomed to code though.

Any help would be so appreciated!

Thank you for taking the time :)

Humbly,
Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON structure has changed so you need to tweak your function **getDailyCMCRates()**

```
var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); //
var dataSet = dataAll.data;//here
var rows = [],data;

for (var i in dataSet) {
  data = dataSet[i];
  rows.push([data.rank, data.name, data.website_slug, data.symbol,  data.id, 
  data.circulating_supply, data.total_supply, data.max_supply, data.quotes.USD.price, 
  data.quotes.USD.market_cap, data.quotes.USD.percent_change_1h, 
  data.quotes.USD.percent_change_24h,data.quotes.USD.percent_change_7d, 
  data.last_updated]);
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for taking the time iJay!

Yes, but how do I access the data in a deeper dimension of the array?

Clarification: The API returns market data for almost 1700 crypto currencies. There are two "categories" in the first dimension of the array, "data" and "metadata". So I use:
 var dataSet = dataAll.data;//here
to access that dimension. 
The next dimension is "categorized" after a unique id for each currency, ranging from 1 and upwards, let's call it the "id-dimension". 
So I try:
 'var dataSet = dataAll.data.1;//here'
and I get the the error:

Comment: "Missing ; before statement." on that line.

Also, the problem is that even if the code managed to enter the "id-dimension" and get the needed data from that there, in the id-dimension there is yet another one namned "quotes"  and in there yet another one namned "USD" where I also want to access data from. All of this data, from both the id-dimension and USD-dimension I then want to print to google sheets.

Comment: AND for every cryptocurrency. So first all the data from id 1 being bitcoin, then all the data from id 2 being ethereum, then 3 and so on until all currencies' data have been printed to google sheets.

Comment: As far as I understand this would basically mean that I would have to assign each id from the "id-dimension" to a separate var dataSet and loop through all of the currencies as there are as many id:s as currencies since every id is unique for that currency. If this is the best way to do it, how do I code to get it to automatically reassign a the next "id-dimension" to var dataSet? Still I'm thinking there must be a better and more efficient way to do it.

Sorry again for my ignorance :)

Comment: @Gazelle use the bracket accessor, rather than the dot operator, when you are accessing a numeric property or a property that is the value of a variable: `var someVar = 1; Logger.log(data[someVar]);`

Comment: Ok, I see and understand regarding a numeric property. Thanks @tehhowch !
But this still only answers part of the question. 

If my property is unique and I need to specify it to be able to access arrays within that property, how do I loop so all of the unique proporties (all currencies in this case) are printed to google sheets? Even if a access beacket is used the problem remains:

Comment: `function getDailyCMCRates() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("getAPI");

var url="https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/"; 
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); 

var myVar = 1;
var dataSet = dataAll.data[myVar]; //here

var rows = [],data;

for (var i in dataSet) {
  data = dataSet[i];

  rows.push([data.quotes.USD.price, data.name]); 
}

dataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, rows.length, 2);
dataRange.setValues(rows);
}`

Comment: the value for `myVar` needs to be changed to access the data from the other currencies. no matter what I do the above will give errors..

Comment: @Gazelle reading code in comments is not ideal or, in general, useful. If your original question had multiple parts, consider splitting it up into answerable chunks, with each question focusing on a specific issue you are having problems overcoming (and including the relevant background research and solution attempts you've made)

Comment: @Gazelle Hope you are still looking ans for this. Sorry I was away. `var dataSet = dataAll.data;` will gather all cryptocurrencies on `data` node. then `for (var i in dataSet) {` is looping through each cryptocurrency. Have you tried my answer replacing the lines that you have tried?

Comment: @iJay Thank you for getting back! Yes, just got it working with your code. :)
Top notch mate! Very appreciated!